# Subtract with SQL in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two table

```
Tab1
ProductID  Productname Qty
1          A            20
2          B            20      

Tab2
ProductID  Productname Qty
1          A            5
2          B            10 
1          A             6
```

I want to subtract Qty from tab1 to tab2 based on ProductID and I want a table like the follwing

```
ProductID     Qty
1              9
2              10
```

How can I do it in MS Access using SQL and without using SQL. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
select tab1.ProductID, 
       sum(tab1.qty) - sum(tab2.qty) as total
from tab1 
left join tab2 on tab1.ProductID = tab2.ProductID
group by tab1.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might like this, which adds to Juergens answer:

```
select tab1.ProductID 
       , tab1.Productname 
       , tab1.Qty
       , tab2.Qty
       , diff.total
from ( tab1 
       left join tab2 
       on tab1.ProductID = tab2.ProductID
     )  
     INNER JOIN 
    (  select tab1.ProductID, 
               sum(tab1.qty) - sum(tab2.qty) as total
        from tab1 
             left join tab2 
             on tab1.ProductID = tab2.ProductID
        group by tab1.ProductID
    ) AS Diff
    ON Diff.ProductID =  tab1.ProductID
```

With regards to doing it without SQL in access - you can't!  You could use excel and vlookup formulas (which are similar to joining tables together in access)

Comment: Did you find the above useful?  If so please flag as an answer.